# How to pass Screen Name to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-component

I have a common `Header` component. How can I pass 'Screen Name' to this component?

I want to pass the 'Screen Name' from `Home` to `HeaderStyle`.

I want to use the `headerstyle` in other component and pass 'Screen Name' to the `headerstyle`

```js
import HeaderStyle From './HeaderStyle '

export default class Home extends Component {
    render (){
        return (
        // <HeaderStyle>Screen Name</HeaderStyle>
        <HeaderStyle Name={"Screen Name"}/>
        <HeaderStyle />
        )
    }
```

```js
  export default class HeaderStyle extends Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header >
                    <View style={{
                        width: width, height: hp('12%'),
                        flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#141414'
                    }} >

                        <Left>
                            <Image style={styles.logo}
                                source={require('../assets/images/1x/logo.png')}>
                            </Image>
                        </Left>

                        <View style={{ marginLeft: 280, marginTop: 20 }}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 35, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                                Should be Dynamic Screen Name</Text></View>

                        <Right>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.ShowHideComponent2}>
                                <Image style={styles.imgsearch} source={require('../assets/test/a.png')}>
                                </Image>

                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </Right>

                    </View>

                </Header>
                {this.showAssests()}
            </View>
        );
     }
  }
```

Comment: can you post more code that from which component you are sending the props value and where you have to use that value in the above component

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and read `window.location.pathname` , then in Header component render that function, for Example

```
export default function currentScreenName(){
   let screenName = '';
   switch(window.location.pathname){
     case '/employees':
        screenName = 'Employees';
        break;
     case '/admin':
        screenName = 'Admin';
        break;
     default:
        screenName = 'Dashboard';
   }
   return screenName;
}

//Header.js
<h1>{currentScreenName()}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the `header` prop in `static navigationOptions` directly **inside** the screen component.

For example

In your screen component

```
    class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        header: <HeaderStyle Name={"Screen Name"}/>
       };
      /* render function, etc */
    }
```

Inside `HeaderStyle` component use the props in the Text

```
 <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 35, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
     {this.props.Name}
 </Text>
```

Find more information on header customisation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html)

Comment: thank you but  in the HeaderStyle how to receive the Name and put it inside render 

render() {
return (

 <Text>{Name}</Text>
)
}

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot i solve the problem

in the home Screen i send the screen name like this

```
            <Headerstyle  title={"text"} />
```

and in the HeaderStyle i receive the title like this

```
<Text >{this.props.title}</Text>
```